# Checking Duplication from Duplicate data

Tags: sql

I have District, Tehsil, Schools code and School Name in following pattern:

```
District Tehsil  SchCode        SchName
A          AA    11111111       AA1
A          AA    11111111       AA2
A          AA    11111111       AA3
B          BB    22222222       BB1
B          BB    22222222       BB2
B          BB    22222222       BB3
```

I want to check duplication in SchCode whether a same SchCode is assigned to any other school having same or different SchName.

Please suggest SQL Server Query for this. I am using SQL Server 2008 Exp

Answer (score 1):

You can join with a correlated subquery that groups by that column:

```
SELECT t1.District, t1.Tehsil, t1.SchCode, t1.SchName
FROM dbo.TableName t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT SchCode 
            FROM dbo.TableName 
            GROUP BY SchCode HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) dup
ON t1.SchCode = dup.SchCode
```

[**Sql-fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/01a76/6/0) that returns all rows because all are duplicates of another.

If you instead just want to know if a record has a duplicate you could use this query:

```
SELECT t1.District, t1.Tehsil, t1.SchCode, t1.SchName, 
       hasDuplicate = CASE WHEN dup.SchCode IS NULL THEN 'no' ELSE 'yes' END
FROM dbo.TableName t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT SchCode 
                 FROM dbo.TableName 
                 GROUP BY SchCode HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) dup
ON t1.SchCode = dup.SchCode
```

[**Sql-fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f3210/2/0) with modified data to get a  non-duplicate.

Comment: Tim it returns all the rows, I want list of SchCode which appeared more than once for different or same schools, I am sure you r getting my point.

Comment: @ShahNawaz: why do you specify that the duplicate must have a "different or same school"? That doesn't make any sense since then that column doesn't matter anyway or is there a third option besides _different_ and _same_.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
;WITH cte AS 
(SELECT   Row_number() OVER (partition BY schcode ORDER BY schname) id,* 
 FROM     tablename ) 
SELECT * 
FROM   tablename a 
JOIN   (SELECT   id,schcode ,count(1)
        FROM     cte 
        GROUP BY id,schcode 
        HAVING   Count(1) > 1)) B 
ON     a.schcode = b.schcode
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM   tablename a 
JOIN   (SELECT   schname,schcode ,count(1)
        FROM     tablename 
        GROUP BY schname,schcode 
        HAVING   Count(1) > 1)) B 
ON     a.schcode = b.schcode
```